# set `exclude_from_indexes` for Array datatype

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I'm storing a list of *strings* using `Array` datatype in Datastore(e.g. ["name1", "name2", ...]). As the list grows, I find myself unable to upsert the entry.

> INVALID_ARGUMENT: Too many indexed properties

According to https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#array, even if I set the property to be `exclude_from_indexes`, it gets ignored. The datastore web UI also doesn't have an `Index` checkmark for me to uncheck.

So the only option I came up with is to convert the `Array` into a `String` type and parse to a JSON Object every time I read from DB, and write back stringified.

Was wondering if this is the right approach or if there are better ways to do this I'm not aware of.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this issue by changing the way I was submitting data to Datastore. I was using this code:

```
this.datastore.save({
   key: this.datastore.key({
       path: [kind]
   }),
   excludeFromIndexes: def.getPropertiesExcludedFromIndex(kind),
   data: entity
});
```

This code works unless the entity is an array, in which case `excludeFromIndexes` is ignored. The solution is to pass `entity` through a formatter before submitting it to Datastore. My formatter looks like this:

```
private formatDataForSave(kind: string, entity: any) {
   const propertiesExcludedFromIndex = def.getPropertiesExcludedFromIndex(kind);
   return Object.entries(entity)
      .filter(([propertyName, propertyValue]) => propertyValue !== undefined && propertyValue !== null)
      .map(([propertyName, propertyValue]) => {
         return {
            name: propertyName,
            value: propertyValue,
            excludeFromIndexes: propertiesExcludedFromIndex.includes(propertyName)
         };
   });
}
```

For some reason, this causes Datastore to format the array correctly and insert `excludeFromIndexes` into each element of the array.

Answer (score -1):

You should set the exclude_from_indexes on each value of the array.  That is what "For a property to be unindexed, the exclude_from_indexes field of Value must be set to true." means.